# How to make Backspace button remove a previous character only?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Is it possible to modify the default functionality of the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button in Android Studio?

I would like the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to always remove only one character (as it was in Eclipse). Currently, clicking the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sometimes reverts me to the previous line, not removes the one previous character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly here is what you have to do!
Open setting and search for "Smart keys" in the search bar, then replace backspace functionality like in the picture.

[image: IMG]